# If i select select option radio button sholud be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here some code 
when i click radio button select option changed, but when i select option selected radio but not checked

```
<select  id="flight_select">
```

```js
$('.select-change').click(function(){ 
    $('#flight_select').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change');
})
```

```
<select  id="flight_select">        
    <option value="A">Only Fly</option>
    <option value="B">Fly + Bag</option>
    <option value="C">Fly + Bag + Eat</option>
</select>

<input type="radio"  name="flightType" id="only_fly" class="select-change" data-val="A">
<input type="radio" name="flightType" id="fly_bag"  value="fly2" class="select-change" data-val="B">
<input type="radio" name="flightType" id="fly_bag_eat" value="fly3" class="select-change" data-val="C">
```

Comment: check what I have done mate and let me know if this is what you want done. https://jsfiddle.net/trhqes25/2/

Comment: Should you use the `change` event listener? https://jsfiddle.net/trhqes25/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the change event of dropdown and then based on the selected value check the radio button.

```js
$('.select-change').change(function() {
  $('#flight_select').val($(this).data('val'));
});

// attach change event handler
$('#flight_select').change(function() {
  // select radio based on `data-val` attribute
  // and then set the checked property
  $('.select-change[data-val="' + this.value + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="flight_select">
  <option value="A">Only Fly</option>
  <option value="B">Fly + Bag</option>
  <option value="C">Fly + Bag + Eat</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" name="flightType" id="only_fly" class="select-change" data-val="A">
<input type="radio" name="flightType" id="fly_bag" value="fly2" class="select-change" data-val="B">
<input type="radio" name="flightType" id="fly_bag_eat" value="fly3" class="select-change" data-val="C">
```

---

**FYI :** It's always better to use change event instead of click event for the radio button since click event will fire even when you are clicking the checked radio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `change` event on `select` element, Also `.trigger('change')` is redundant.

```js
$('.select-change').click(function() {
  $('#flight_select').val($(this).data('val'));
});

$('#flight_select').change(function() {
  $('.select-change[data-val=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('checked', true)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="flight_select">
  <option value="A">Only Fly</option>
  <option value="B">Fly + Bag</option>
  <option value="C">Fly + Bag + Eat</option>
</select>

<input type="radio" name="flightType" id="only_fly" class="select-change" data-val="A">
<input type="radio" name="flightType" id="fly_bag" value="fly2" class="select-change" data-val="B">
<input type="radio" name="flightType" id="fly_bag_eat" value="fly3" class="select-change" data-val="C">
```